# Why can't I initialize a reference to `ofstream` / `ifstream`, with an instance of `fstream`?

Tags: c++, reference, fstream, ifstream, ostream

#### INTRODUCTION

```
void  read_foo (std::ifstream& out);
void write_foo (std::ofstream& out);
```

I have these two functions where one is supposed to read from a file, and the other is supposed to write to one.

Everything works having the below snippets;

```
std::ifstream ifs ("filename.txt");
read_foo  (ifs);
```

```
std::ofstream ofs ("filename.txt");
write_foo (ofs);
```

---

### THE PROBLEM

However, if I try to use a `std::fstream`, so I can call both functions with the same stream, it doesn't compile, and the compiler spits out a lot of error messages.

- Why can't I bind a `fstream` to an `ifstream&`, or `ofstream&`?

---

#### foo.cpp

```
#include <fstream>

void  read_foo (std::ifstream& out);
void write_foo (std::ofstream& out);

int main () {
  std::fstream fs ("filename.txt");

   read_foo (fs);
  write_foo (fs);
}
```

#### Error(s):

> `foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> foo.cpp:9:16: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::ifstream& {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>&}’ from expression of type ‘std::fstream {aka std::basic_fstream<char>}’
>      read_foo (fs);
>                  ^
> foo.cpp:3:7: note: in passing argument 1 of ‘void read_foo(std::ifstream&)’  void  read_foo (std::ifstream& out);`

> `foo.cpp:10:16: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::ofstream& {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>&}’ from expression of type ‘std::fstream {aka std::basic_fstream<char>}’
>      write_foo (fs);
>                   ^
> foo.cpp:4:6: note: in passing argument 1 of ‘void write_foo(std::ofstream&)’  void write_foo (std::ofstream& out);`

Comment: The ones downvoting, why is this question worthy of **-1**?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### *"THE LONG STORY; SHORT"* - ANSWER

Since a `std::fstream` is not derived from either `std::ofstream`, nor `std::ifstream`, the reference is not *"compatible"* with the instance of `std::fstream`.

Use `std::istream&` and `std::ostream&`, instead of `std::ifstream&` and `std::ofstream&` (respectively).

```
void write_data (std::ostream&);
void  read_data (std::istream&);
```

---

#### INTRODUCTION

As the compiler is trying to tell you; `std::fstream` does not inherit from `std::ifstream`, therefore you cannot initialize a reference to the latter with a value of the former.

I've stumbled upon several developers who seem to assume that `std::fstream`, behind the scenes, is some sort of direct merge between a `std::ifstream`, and a `std::ofstream`, and that it is implemented by deriving from both.

When asked why they think that is the case, many think that the answer can be summed up with; *"because it makes sense, right?"*

---

#### THE SILLY ANALOGY

Imagine that we have three siblings; *Ivan*, *Owen*, and *John*, living in a family where *reading* and *writing* is everything.

All brothers were born with a gift;

- *Ivan* is great at reading, and has given it his whole life, he never does anything else, and;
- *Owen* has a thing for writing, which is odd since he can't read, and;
- *John* got lucky and got both the skill of *reading* and *writing*.

Just because *John* can do both of the things his brothers can, doesn't mean that they are his parents - they are, after all; his brothers.

All three brothers has inherited their certain traits from other relatives, not each other.

---

#### THE ANSWER

`std::fstream` is not built "on top of" `std::{i,o}fstream`,  even though they share certain parts of their individual inheritance tree.

> [image: iostreams inheritance visualized]
>
> ***src**: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io*

When accepting a stream in generic code you should not care about the "*real*" type of the underlying stream.

Does it really matter if we pass in a *std::stringstream*, *std::fstream*, or *std::ofstream* to our function which writes some output data to a *stream*? No, all we care about is the ability to *read/write*.

We express this by forming a reference to either `std::istream`, `std::ostream`, or `std::iostream`, when we need a stream which can;*read*, *write*, or *both*, respectively.

( **Note**: IF it's not obvious: *Ivan*  is an *ifstream*, *Owen* an *ofstream*, and *John* a *fstream*. )

Comment: Good explanation, and it shows the limitations of OO. (With templates, the code would work because `fstream` offers the methods of both `ifstream` and `ofstream`)